Failed to open file .curltmp. error using curl_download in Rstudio
I am trying to download an ftp file from ncbi on R-4.3.3 (Windows) but am unsuccessful as I keep getting this error below. From what I understand download.files does not work to ftp files anymore as wininet for ftp is defunct, but would be open to any alternative methods. Would appreciate some input.
tried:
url <-"ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/M_musculus/mRNA_Prot/mouse.1.protein.faa.gz"
tmp <- "C:/Windows/Temp.curl"
curl_download(url, tmp)
Error in curl_download(url, tmp) : 
  Failed to open file C:\Windows\Temp.curl.curltmp.

expected:
download ftp file to destination tmp


2nd parameter is the destination file; make sure it's in some existing directory where you have write permissions. And by default, download.file() uses libcurl instead of wininet in Windows, at least for ftp:// URLs. If it behaves differently on your system, you may have it set through the download.file.method option. Anyway, both curl::curl_download() and download.file() work fine with ftp:// URLs in Windows:
url <-"ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/M_musculus/mRNA_Prot/mouse.1.protein.faa.gz"
# per-session temporary directory
tmp <- tempdir()

(cdl_out <- file.path(tmp, paste0("cdl_",basename(url))))
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\marguslt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpcp5IMg/cdl_mouse.1.protein.faa.gz"
curl::curl_download(url, cdl_out)

(dlf_out <- file.path(tmp, paste0("dlf_",basename(url))))
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\marguslt\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpcp5IMg/dlf_mouse.1.protein.faa.gz"
download.file(url, dlf_out, mode = "wb")

# list downloaded files
fs::dir_info(tmp, glob = "*.gz")[1:3]
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   path                                                               type   size
#>   <fs::path>                                                         <fct> <fs:>
#> 1 …marguslt/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcp5IMg/cdl_mouse.1.protein.faa.gz file  5.02M
#> 2 …marguslt/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcp5IMg/dlf_mouse.1.protein.faa.gz file  5.02M

# system info and download.file.method
Sys.info()[1:3] 
#>       sysname       release       version 
#>     "Windows"      "10 x64" "build 19045"
options()$download.file.method
#> "libcurl"

